# Mask subdomain using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want to mask my subdomain to a specific url on my main domain using .htaccess.

For example: https://sub.example.com to show the content of https://www.example.com/page/12345.
And the URL is still https://sub.example.com

I have got the following in .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.example\.com
RewriteRule ^https://sub\.example\.com https://www\.example\.com/page/12345
```

But if I go to https://sub.example.com, it shows content of https://www.example.com. Can't seem to figure out what's wrong. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you want to rewrite without redirecting. This requires enabling mod_proxy and mod_rewrite in Apache's httpd.conf.

Then, the rewrite should look like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^sub\.example\.com$ [NC]
#only when there is query string and https on, if needed
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule ^$ https://www.example.com/page/12345? [R=301,NE,NC,L]
```

Reference:

- [What exactly does the Multiviews options in .htaccess?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25423141/what-exactly-does-the-multiviews-options-in-htaccess)
- [htaccess rewrite without redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10452907/htaccess-rewrite-without-redirect)
- [Apache: RewriteRule Flags](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html)